# Contradiction in definition

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I  have  a  question  here . They  say ker($\tau^c$)=$\{0\}$ . The  restriction  of  $\tau$  on  ker$(\tau)^c$   is  $\tau^c$  and  $0\in ker(\tau)$  so  $)$  is  not  in ker$(\tau)^c$ . .  How  can  $0$  be  in  ker($\tau^c$)  $?$  Is  not  a  Contradiction  $?$

Comment: $0$ is always in every subspace. Question is either incorrect or confusing. Please clarify the question further.

Comment: Direct sum is not disjoint union.

Comment: @egreg : ok. So,how does  that help  me  here ? . I was  thinking  that  the  *complement sign* $c$  meant  disjoint, not  the  *direct sum*  sign. .  But  in  this  case  looks  like  ,  $B=A^c$  implies  $A\cap B=\{0\}$ .Why $?$

Comment: @user118494 The notation is not what I'd use, because a complementary subspace is not unique; but it definitely doesn't mean the set theoretic complement. Go back in the book where the notion of complementary subspace is defined and it is proved that every subspace (of a finite dimensional vector space) has a complement.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are maybe confused by the word *complement*. Note, that a *vector space complement* for $\ker\tau$ is **not** given by $\ker\tau$'s *set theoretic complement*.

A (vector space) complement for $\ker \tau$ is a subspace (note the indefinite article, it is not uniquely determined) $(\ker\tau)^c$ such that any $v \in V$ can uniquely be represented as 
$$ v = u + u', \quad u \in \ker \tau, u' \in (\ker \tau)^c $$
As $(\ker\tau)^c$ is a subspace, it of course contains $0$ (and be the unique decomposition property above $\ker \tau \cap (\ker\tau)^c = \{0\}$).

The (set theoretic) complement for $\ker \tau$ is the set (note the article, it is unique) $\complement(\ker \tau) := V \setminus (\ker \tau)$, it plays seldom an important role in linear algebra.

Comment: *Indifferent article*  $?$

Comment: Yes, you are right  *complement*  is  what  confused  me .

Comment: @user118494 *indefinite*, sry

Comment: but  again  what  is  the  *indefinite article*  $?$

Comment: "a/an" vs. "the". The complement is a uniquely determined entity, where "a complement" is one among many.

Comment: Ohh , that  thing  from english  grammar ,we were  taught in school  but  forgot the name. now I  understand .  ha ha ,. I thought  you  meant  some  theory  of  that  name .